# Chart.js use font awesome in labels

Tags: javascript, chart.js, font-awesome

I'm unsuccessfully trying to show font awesome characters as labels in chart.js

1.I added fontawesome's css

2.I set the char from https://fontawesome.com/cheatsheet

3.I edited chart.js options to set `pointLabels.fontFamily` to `FontAwesome` but it never loads the unicodes, while emojis do (the battery one).

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var myRadarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'radar',
    data: {
        labels: ['', '', "\uf461", '\uf368', '\uf558'],
        datasets: [{
        data: [20, 10, 4, 2,1]
        }]
    },
    options: {
      scale: {
          pointLabels: {
            fontFamily: "FontAwesome",
          }
      }
  }
});
```

Full code:
http://jsfiddle.net/vm9o6bfs/2/

¿What i'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue and fixed it wrapping the fontFamily in `'` like this.

```
fontFamily: '"Font Awesome 5 Free"'
```

Take a look to this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/picassofb/a92kdqvy/4/)